# How to plot multiple boxplots with a single variable each on ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
01/02/2013 02/02/2013 03/02/2013 04/02/2013
    1          2          3          3   
    2          1          6          7 
    3          3          4          2
    4          1          1          8
```

I want to make a graph with n boxplots according to the number of the columns in my dataset, where each boxplot only contains one variable which is its corresponding column. So in this case, there would be 4 boxplots.

I used `boxplot()` function and it worked for my data, however I want to use `geom_jitter()` from `ggplot2` to beautify my plots. And `ggplot2` requires both x and y axes where I don't really have with my dataset.

This is what I want for my plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package (is in `tidyverse`)
2. use `ggplot` from `ggplot2` package (is also in `tidyverse`)
3. `geom_boxplot` and `geom_jitter` if needed.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with("X"),
        names_to = "names",
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=names, y=values, fill=names))+
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter(aes(y=values))
```

[image]